# How to load Image() in JavaScript without caching it on Safari

Tags: javascript, image, caching, safari

On Safari, i would like to load an image in JavaScript like that:

```
var img = new Image();
var src = ....
```

But i don't want to put this image in the browser cache.
Any idea ?

FOR SAFARI ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `User-agent` header on server side to see if this request is coming from Safari, then set `Cache-Control: no-cache` for the response header.